# Rake script doesn't work after changing column to datetime in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, datetime, schema

I have just changed a column (called time) from t.string to t.datetime and then dropped and re-created the database and run the migration.

I have a script set to run every minute that scrapes information from a remote website and then adds the information to new records based on the time column that I adjusted to be a datetime rather than string.

```
# Add each row to a new call record
page = agent.page.search("table tbody tr").each do |row|
next if (!row.at('td'))
time, source, destination, duration = row.search('td').map{ |td| td.text.strip }
call = Call.find_or_create_by_time(time)
call.update_attributes({:time => time, :source => source, :destination => destination, :duration => duration})
end
```

Since changing the time column to integer the script doesn't seem to be importing any information at all. I wondered if there is an extra step that I need to do to make this work again?

My schema looks like this:

```
create_table "calls", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "source"
    t.string   "duration"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.string   "destination"
    t.string   "recording"
    t.string   "cost"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part

```
time, source, destination, duration = row.search('td').map{ |td| td.text.strip }
call = Call.find_or_create_by_time(time)
```

you get `time` variable as a string, and trying to `find_by` it. I think smth like

```
call = Call.find_or_create_by_time(Time.parse(time))
```

should do the trick